# K-fold Cross Validation with early stopping on a deep learning model

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation

I know there are similar questions, but so far when the topic of early stopping comes up I can't find a decisive answer.
I want to know if what I'm doing makes sense and if not why. When I say "test set" I'm talking about the hold out set that the model won't see at any point during training time.

So my pipeline for k-fold validation is the following:

1. I have my original dataset and I split it into 2 in a 80/20
   proportion. These are my train and test sets. The test set won't be
   used until the end.
2. I perform a 5 folds cross validation using my train split.
3. Each split has a train subset and validation subset, again in a 80/20
   proportion. For each split I train a model using the train subset,
   early stopping is performed using the validation subset. After
   training each split I'm left with 5 models.

In broad terms these are my steps.

Here's part 2 of my question:

Now I want the estimate of that model's performance (precision, recall, f1, etc), should I evaluate all 5 model using my original test set (data it has not seen at any point) and take the mean of the results?
For production could I take the fold with the smaller val loss? I know you are supposed to train over all the training data, but the problem is that I would need a validation set for early stopping.